# How do i use pagenation in my code,my app crashes while scrolling recyclerview?

Tags: android

I am trying to show JSON response in my app which shows icons and title in my app,i used recyclerview to list item vertically on the cardview.But my app Crashes while i scroll down ,i google some sollution it says to use pagination.I never use pagination.Help me assap

```
 class ListSourceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener
    {
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    TextView source_title;
    CircleImageView source_image;
    public ListSourceViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        source_image=(CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_image);
        source_title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_name);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}
     public class ListSourceAdapter 
     extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<ListSourceViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private WebSite webSite;
    private IconBetterIdeaService mService;

    public ListSourceAdapter(Context context, WebSite webSite) {
        this.context = context;
        this.webSite = webSite;
        mService= Common.getIconService();
    }

    @Override
    public ListSourceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.source_layout,parent,false);
        return new ListSourceViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListSourceViewHolder holder, final int 
    position) {
     StringBuilder iconBetterAPI=new StringBuilder("https://icons.better-
    idea.org/allicons.json?url=");
        iconBetterAPI.append(webSite.getSources().get(position).getUrl());
        mService.getIconUrl(iconBetterAPI.toString()).enqueue(new 
    Callback<IconBetterIdea>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<IconBetterIdea> call, 
    Response<IconBetterIdea> response) {

    if (response.body().getIcons().size() > 0)
     {
           Picasso.with(context).load(response.body().getIcons().get(0).getUrl()).into(holder.source_image);

                    }
                }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<IconBetterIdea> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    holder.source_title.setText(webSite.getSources().get(position).getName());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, ListNews.class);
                intent.putExtra("source", 
                webSite.getSources().get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("sortBy", 

            webSite.getSources().get(position).getSortBysAvailable().get(0));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

     @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return webSite.getSources().size();
    }
    }


//Here is my mainActivity
package pay4free.in.primenews;

import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import io.paperdb.Paper;
import pay4free.in.primenews.Adapter.ListSourceAdapter;
import pay4free.in.primenews.Common.Common;
import pay4free.in.primenews.Interface.NewsService;
import pay4free.in.primenews.Model.WebSite;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView listWebsite;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    NewsService mService;
    ListSourceAdapter adapter;
    SpotsDialog Dialog;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Paper.init(this);
        mService= Common.getNewsService();
      swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                loadWebsiteSource(true);
            }
        });
        listWebsite=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_source);
        listWebsite.setHasFixedSize(false);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        listWebsite.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Dialog=new SpotsDialog(this);
        loadWebsiteSource(false);

    }

    private void loadWebsiteSource(boolean isRefreshed) {
if(!isRefreshed)
{
    String cache =Paper.book().read("cache");
    if(cache!=null&&!cache.isEmpty())
    {
        WebSite webSite=new Gson().fromJson(cache,WebSite.class);
        adapter=new ListSourceAdapter(getBaseContext(),webSite);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listWebsite.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else
    {
        Dialog.show();
        mService.getSources().enqueue(new Callback<WebSite>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WebSite> call, Response<WebSite> response) {
                adapter=new ListSourceAdapter(getBaseContext(),response.body());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listWebsite.setAdapter(adapter);
                Paper.book().write("cache",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WebSite> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
else
{
    Dialog.show();
    mService.getSources().enqueue(new Callback<WebSite>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WebSite> call, Response<WebSite> response) {
            adapter=new ListSourceAdapter(getBaseContext(),response.body());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listWebsite.setAdapter(adapter);

            Paper.book().write("cache",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WebSite> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Help me,my app get crashes when i scroll down to the bottom.

Comment: you should include your log to get more details about the crash

Comment: i am able to see all data but when i scroll down i get back to the previous page

Comment: as app get restarted i am not able to see error in my logcat

Answer (score 0):

You are creating adapter every time.Create adapter only once and update it.
Remove these lines

```
adapter=new ListSourceAdapter(getBaseContext(),response.body());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listWebsite.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create a method to update the data in your adapter.

```
adapter.yourMethodToUpdate(response.body());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: nothing..just what you were doing inside the constructor.Store it in Website object like before

Comment: if i remove above line how will i pass my parameter (call,response 
)to the method?

Comment: Only once in oncreate you call it.Then call the method and update it.